# Tornado webapp page has elements from extended template but missing all other elements

Tags: python, html, tornado

I'm creating a webapp with Tornado, and I'm having this issue where an .html page I have is extending another .html page like so:

```
{%extends "sitebase.html" %}
<div id="about">
 <p>hello</p>
</div>
```

When I serve this page, I see the correct content from 'sitebase.html' (a simple nav bar), however I don't see the 'hello' on the web page. I've inspected the page and don't even see an element with this 'hello', and there are no errors in the console. When I remove the extends block and just paste the contents of sitebase.html I see the expected result.

Has anyone else had this experience with tornado where using an extend block causes other pieces of the page to be not rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/template.html#syntax-reference) (emphasis mine):

> `{% extends *filename* %}`
>
> Inherit from another template. Templates that use extends should contain one or more `block` tags to replace content from the parent template. **Anything in the child template not contained in a `block` tag will be ignored**. For an example, see the `{% block %}` tag.

This means that when you extend a template, the content within a `{% block %}` tag is rendered, anything outside the tag is ignored.

Example:

*base.html*:

```
<title>{% block title %}Default title{% end %}</title>

{% block content %}
{% end %}
```

*mytemplate.html*:

```
{% block title %}Title for this page{% end %}

{% block content %}
  Some data to render in the content block
{% end %}

This will not be rendered because it is outside a block tag
```

Comment: Thank you! It's my first time using templates and I didn't have the {% block content %} in the template I was trying to extend